# How can i overcome AWS Aurora Data api timeout in 45seconds

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

AWS Aurora Data api(I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-api-client) has a fatal drawback of a 45-second timeout, is there a way to overcome it?

The search results found approximately 2 ways.

1. set continueAfterTimeout True. Error occurs, but query runs normally. However, the transaction is rolled back.
2. If a timeout exception occurs, wait a few seconds in try-catch. I don't think it's a good idea to wait in a situation where we don't know when it'll end.

Is there any other good way? Please tell me

Comment: Hello @Doo9104, I'm facing the same issue. did you figure out a solution? thanks in advance.